# Given $m\in[0,1]$, can we find a dense subset of $[0,1]$ whose Lebesgue measure is exactly $m$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the collection of subsets $A$ of the unit interval $[0,1]$ which are dense, meaning that for every $x\in[0,1]$, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $|x-a|<\varepsilon$. What are the Lebesgue measures of these sets?

Clearly these sets are bounded above by the unit interval itself, which is dense and has Lebesgue measure $1$. On the other hand, the set $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ is dense and has Lebesgue measure null.

My question is this: for any $m\in[0,1]$, does there exist a dense subset $A\subseteq[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $m$?

---

Edit: I found out that if $A$ has measure $m$ and satisfies $|A\cap I|=m|I|$ for every interval $I\subseteq[0,1]$ (a better, stronger condition) where $|\cdot|$ denotes Lebesgue measure, then the density at a point $x\in A$ is given by

$$ d(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}
\frac{|A\cap(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)|}{|(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)|}
= \begin{cases} |A|/2 & \text{if } x=0\text{ or }1 \\
|A| & \text{if }x\in(0,1) \end{cases}$$

Lebesgue's density theorem says that if $A$ is measurable then $d(x)=1$ for almost all $x\in A$, and since we established $d(x)=|A|$ for $x\in(0,1)$, which is almost all of $[0,1]$, this implies $|A|=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes. For $m\in [0,1]$ consider the set $A:=[0,m]\cup(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])$.
This is clearly dense and has measure $m$.

Comment: Great! However, this set is quite "lop-sided". I am wondering if there is a more evenly distributed example.

Comment: Then I refer to the answer of saz. Take an evenly distributed set of Lebesgue measure $m$ and "add" $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Comment: @M.Nestor Depends on what you mean by evenly distributed. It would be cool if, given a constant $0 < c < 1$, it were possible to find a measurable set $A$ such that $m(A \cap I) = c m(I)$ for every interval $I \subseteq [0,1]$. This turns out to be [impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163417/subset-a-subset-mathbb-r-such-that-for-any-interval-i-of-length-a-the-set)

Comment: @Bungo After reading that post, it seems that what I am after is precisely Lebesgue's density theorem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Well, yes. Just take **any** set $B$ of Lebesgue measure $m$ (e.g. $B=[0,m]$) and consider

$$A := B \cup (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]).$$

The set has Lebesgue measure $m$ and it is dense in $[0,1]$.

It's a bit more tricky to construct an **open** dense set $A$ with small Lebesgue measure $m$. Here, one approach is to consider an enumeration $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $$A := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (q_n-\epsilon 2^{-n},q_n+\epsilon 2^{-n})$$ for fixed $\epsilon>0$. The set $A$ is open and has Lebesgue measure $\leq \epsilon$.

**Remark:** Note that there does not exist an **open** dense set with Lebesgue measure zero. In this sense, the best we can achieve is to have an open dense set of arbitrarily small Lebesgue measure, as above.

Comment: For the 2nd example,  the set must be less than $\epsilon$ since there are some overlaps between those intervals, right?

Comment: @efhvcjnfdbgefg Yes, that's correct. There are plenty of overlaps (... exactly because the rationals are dense).

Comment: In fact $\varepsilon$ must always be an overestimate, since any interval $(q_n-2^{-n}\varepsilon,q_n+2^{-n}\varepsilon)$ must contain another $q_m$, guaranteeing overlap at least $\min\{\varepsilon2^{-m},\varepsilon2^{-n}\}$.

Comment: My above comment doesn't change the validity, since the overestimate varies continuously, you can always find $\varepsilon$ such that the true measure is precisely $m$.

Comment: could you have a look at my construction and tell me if it is fine? Thanks a lot! (see answer below)

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Take 
$$
[0,m]\cup(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])=[0,m]\overset{\cdot}{\cup}(\mathbb{Q}\cap(m,1]).
$$

Answer (score 2):

I am sort of new to topology so I post this as a tentative answer to see if you find it correct. Its a variation of [saz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36150/saz)'s answer, in order to have an open dense subset of $[0,1]$ with measure *exactly* $\varepsilon$.

Let $q_1,q_2,\dots$ be, as usual, an enumeration of the rationals.

Let $A_0 = \emptyset$. For $n\geq 1$ construct an open interval $E_n$ such that $q_n \in E_n$ and $$m(E_n-A_{n-1})=\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}.$$ Then $A_n = A_{n-1}\cup E_n$ has measure
$$m(A_n) = \varepsilon\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2^k}$$
and $$A = A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\dots$$ has measure $\varepsilon$.