# Disjoint subsets $\mathbb{R}^n$ with same Hausdorff measure on open sets

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Can we choose sets $X_1,X_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two disjoint sets with Hausdorff dimension $0\le d \le n$, such that $0<\mathcal{H}^d(X_1)=\mathcal{H}^d(X_2)<\infty$, such that for any open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $\mathcal{H}^d(U \cap X_1)=\mathcal{H}^d(U \cap X_2)$? I know [this is false for Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163417/subset-a-subset-mathbb-r-such-that-for-any-interval-i-of-length-a-the-set), but I don't know if a similar density restriction applies to Hausdorff measure.